# "What is the 'allow overlapping types' option used for in line art modifiers?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, grease-pencil, outliner, lineart

[image]
As I understand it, this option allows for the independent representation of multiple features that overlap on a single edge, allowing for separate lines to be drawn for each feature.

However, I haven't been able to see the actual results when using it. Could you show me what kind of results can be produced when using this option?"

Comment: relevant talk from the line art modifier creator https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x6TE85yXdxw